# html iframe cached content

Tags: html, caching, iframe

I'm using a bootstrap carousel component that has to be in inside an iframe (because it has some error that propagates to other elements otherwise).
This iframe is gonna load the same css and javascript as the parent.
Does the iframe fetches this files from cache or does it have to fetch this files (over the network again) that the parent is also fetching?

Comment: The browser will probably cache the files (in case they are static files) but it also depends on the server (in case the server will send a no-cache header the browser will not cache it). You can open the console and check in the network tab to see the actual requests/responses...

Comment: Thank you @Dekel. It seems that it is fetching from cache, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

iFrame will usually ( with common browsers ) fetch them from cache if proper caching have been implemented. In personal experience, consider the designing / coding  iFrame exactly as you work with its parent. in other words, it is a standard html page